# Calculating distance from starting positions with vectors

Tags: vectors

I'm currently learning about vectors in maths. I recently completed the Unit Vectors topic and I am stuck on this question.

> A boat sails 5 km south-east then 3 km due west. Approximately how far
>   from its starting position is it now?

[image: Diagram of boat travelling]

I'm assuming that O is the origin and starting position. I'm using unit vectors i and j representing east and north respectively.
P is the point after going 5km south-west. I think it is the equation $5i-5j$. 
Q is the finishing position after going 3km west. I'm a little confused if I can give Q the formula $2i-5j$ or not.

I'd like to know if my above thoughts are correct and some assistance with solving this question.

Comment: $P$ is nearer $\dfrac{5}{\sqrt2} i-\dfrac{5}{\sqrt2} j$

Comment: @Henry Could you please explain how you calculated that? I'm confused where the $\sqrt2$ is coming from.

Comment: If $i$ represents the unit vector pointing towards east and $j$ the unit vector pointing towards north where the unit is $1$ km, your calculation is correct. Now you have to calculate or estimate the length your got vector. You should use the Pythagoras theorem because the directions North and West are perpendicular.

Comment: Calculate the length $OP$ using your attempt at $P$ and using mine.

Comment: @Henry Ah I see, Using your definition of P and using Pythagoras the length of $OP$ was 5. I am still a bit confused on how to calculate this. Would you mind explaining further or linking me to a useful resource?

Comment: Broadly speaking you have to convert from polar coordinates (distance and angle) to Cartesian coordinates, probably using expressions like $r\cos \theta$ and $r\sin \theta$, though exactly how you do this depends on whether you measure angles anticlockwise from the horizontal or clockwise from the vertical.